# How to set time limit of function?

Tags: ios, swift2, nstimer, nsdata

In my project I am accessing images from URL. In these URLs I gave 2-3 dummy URL which doesn't have any data. But my code takes more time to access & identifies that there is no imageData on the url. Here is the code

```
func callImageURL(urlString : String) -> UIImage
{


    // define an image
    var contentImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "defaultImage.jpg")!

    // convert String url to NSURL
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    // if url exist
    if (url != nil)
    {
        // fetch the imageData from url
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        // if image data exist
        if (data != nil)
        {
            // convert imagedata back to an image
            contentImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
        }
    }


    return contentImage
}
```

So my question is that how can I put execution time limit on my code. OR Is there any way by which I can make my code more efficient?

Comment: you should use threading so that your screen will not block in any circumstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some time consuming functions, you can call them in background thread and then update UI on main thread.
Code example:

```
func callImageURL(urlString : String, completion: UIImage -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        var contentImage = UIImage(named: "defaultImage.jpg")

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)  {
            contentImage = UIImage(data: data)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completion(contentImage!)
        }
    }
}

callImageURL("your url") {image in
    //Use your image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
```

is a synchronous request so it will block your main thread till it executes. There is no error checking also, might be your url is 404 or might be it is just being `timeout` in which case it might block your main thread for easily over 4 sec.

> Best practice is to use new NSURLSession API to download the image
>   asynchronously. That way the request can be cached as well and you
>   check for appropriate error callbacks without blocking your main
>   thread.

I will suggest to check [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) which can help you with the network request and even progress blocks.